Gitlab CI/CD fails] Error showing: Interrupted: 1 error during collection
Please help why I'm getting this error and what is the solution .

I'm not sure it is becasue my yaml or my test script itself.
Am i missing anything here or it's wrong approach?
My script:
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
d = webdriver.Chrome('/home/<user>/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
d.get('https://www.google.nl/')

    service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    yield driver
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://selenium_standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub', options=webdriver.ChromeOptions())
    driver.quit()

def test_login(driver):
    driver.get("https://websitexxx/login")
    

    # Find the username and password fields and fill them in
    email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'login-email')]")
    password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'login-password')]")

    email.send_keys("xxxx")  # Replace with the actual username
    password.send_keys("xxxx")  # Replace with the actual password

    # Find and click the login button
    login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='submit-btn']")  # Adjust the XPath for the actual button
    login_button.click()

    # Wait for a while to let the login process complete
    time.sleep(10)

    # Check if login was successful by verifying the presence of an element that appears after login
    assert driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'title').text == 'Dashboard'

and my yaml:
image: python:3.11-alpine

stages:
  - test

auto-test:
  stage: test
  services: 
      - selenium/standalone-chrome
  stage: test
  before_script:
    # Install necessary dependencies
    - apk add --no-cache bash curl unzip chromium chromium-chromedriver
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install selenium pytest

    # Verify installation
    - chromium-browser --version
    - chromedriver --version

    # Set up virtual environment
    - python -m venv venv
    - . venv/bin/activate

  script:
    - echo "Running Test Script..."
    - pytest LogTest.py --maxfail=1 --disable-warnings -q --tb=short
  variables:
    # Set Chrome options for headless execution in CI
    DISPLAY: ":99"
    CHROME_BIN: "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
    CHROME_DRIVER: "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

I have tried few solutions but still not working. Please help. Thankyou.

The error message you have posted is saying IndentationError: Unexpected indent and pointing at line 15 service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver"). And sure enough, if I search for that in your script you have an unexpected indent. I would suggest  you fix your python script and try again.
